# Caret location QtQuick TextField

Tags: qml, qtquick2

how can i set Caret location of textField,
for example when onClicked triggered set caret location to some where in textfield :

```
TextField {
            id: fromDateTxt
            inputMask: "0000-00-00"
            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    //set caret location to somewhere in start or middle
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `cursorPosition` property [(See docs)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#cursorPosition-prop)

```
onClicked: {
    //set caret location to end
    cursorPosition = text.length
    focus = true
}
```

Edit: adding focus = true to be able to immediately type

Comment: after using this TextField area wont let you edit text inside it

Comment: @MoreMag I have added focus, so now you start typing immediately